# OpenMesh: remove_property : is not a member of Decimater::DecimaterT<MeshT>

Tags: visual-c++, mesh, openmesh

I'm trying to use the decimater algorithm in `OpenMesh`. I followed the basic setup presented in this link: http://openmesh.org/Documentation/OpenMesh-2.0-Documentation/decimater_docu.html but I get the following error which is comes from the `modquadrict.hh(part of the library)`.

```
error C2039: 'remove_property' : is not a member of 'OpenMesh::Decimater::DecimaterT<MeshT>'
```

main.cpp

```
#include "MyMesh.h"
#include <conio.h>
#include <iostream>


int main()
{
    MyMesh mesh;

    decimater deci (mesh);

    HModQuadric hModQuad;

    if(!OpenMesh::IO::read_mesh(mesh, "models/monkey.obj"));
    {
        std::cout<<"Cannot read mesh";
    }

    deci.add(hModQuad);

    std::cout << deci.module( hM).name() << std::endl;
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

`MyMesh.h`

```
#pragma once

// OpenMesh
#pragma warning(push)
#pragma warning(disable: 4267)
#include <OpenMesh/Core/IO/MeshIO.hh>
#include <OpenMesh/Core/Mesh/TriMesh_ArrayKernelT.hh>
#include <OpenMesh/Tools/Decimater/ModQuadricT.hh>
#include <OpenMesh/Tools/Decimater/DecimaterT.hh>
#pragma warning(pop)

//Additional mesh parameters
struct MeshTraits : public OpenMesh::DefaultTraits
{
    VertexAttributes(OpenMesh::Attributes::Normal);
    FaceAttributes(OpenMesh::Attributes::Normal);
};

typedef OpenMesh::TriMesh_ArrayKernelT<MeshTraits>  MyMesh;

// Decimater type
typedef OpenMesh::Decimater::DecimaterT< MyMesh >               decimater;

// Decimation Module Handle type
typedef OpenMesh::Decimater::ModQuadricT< decimater >::Handle HModQuadric;
```

Comment: Are you calling remove property from the mesh class or directly from the decimeter, can u post some code?

Comment: I have added some code with which I'm trying to test the decimater. Even before attempting to call the decimate method or initialize the decimater I'm getting the above error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was with this line.

typedef OpenMesh::Decimater::ModQuadricT< **decimater** >::Handle HModQuadric;

it should be like this:

typedef OpenMesh::Decimater::ModQuadricT< **MyMesh** >::Handle HModQuadric;

I was referring the documentation from version 2.0 while working on version 3.0

With recent versions, the templating depend on the mesh and not the decimater.

Comment: Feel free to accept your own answer as it is correct.